# Python kivy asyncio как запускать одновременно

Tags: python, kivy, asyncio

Пишу клиент для сервера с помощью python kivy.Как мне одновременно подключаться к серверу и открывать окно. У меня подключается к серверу, но окно не запускается

```
import asyncio
from asyncio import transports
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window 
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import (
    NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
)

Window.size = (400,800)




class ClientProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    transport: transports.Transport
    window: 'Chat'

    def __init__(self, chat):
        self.window = chat

    def data_received(self, data: bytes):
        print(data)
        decoded = data.decode()
        self.window.label.text = decoded

    def connection_made(self, transport: transports.Transport):
        self.window.label.text = "Успешно подключились, введите логин"
        self.transport = transport

    def connection_lost(self, exception):
        self.window.label.text = "Вы отключены от сервера"


class Chat(BoxLayout):
    protocol: ClientProtocol

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def send_message(self):
        message = self.textinput.text()
        self.textinput.clear()
        self.protocol.transport.write(message.encode())

    def create_protocol(self):
        self.protocol = ClientProtocol(self)
        return self.protocol

    async def start(self):


        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

        coroutine = loop.create_connection(
            self.create_protocol,
            "127.0.0.1",
            8888
        )

        await asyncio.wait_for(coroutine, 1000)



loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
process = Chat()
asyncio.run(process.start())
loop.run_forever()

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Chat()

MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

`loop.run_forever()` и `MyApp().run()` - разные штуки которые блокируют программу. Вам нужно или `run` положить в тред либо запустить киви на loop

```
import asyncio
from kivy.app import async_runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.label import Label

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

app = loop.run_until_complete((
    async_runTouchApp(MyApp(), async_lib='asyncio'))

loop.create_task(app.start())
loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```

Тут ещё надо конекшн сохранить..

```
self.conn = await asyncio.wait_for(coroutine, 1000)
```

Comment: мне выдает ошибку  AttributeError: 'MyApp' object has no attribute 'parent'

Comment: Надо смотреть детали, пример что был понятен принцип